# A PHP Error was encountered Message: Undefined variable: menu - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

```
<?php

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

    private $menu;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('menu_model');

        $this->$menu = $this->menu_model->generateTree($items = array());
    }

    public function index() {
        $data['menu'] = $this->$menu;
        $this->load->view('dashboard/dashboard', $data);
    }

}
```

Hi guys, I get menu details at the constructor like this.I can get the result also. but it comes with the error 
"A PHP Error was encountered 
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: menu
"

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: You should have created an MCVE first, as per site guidelines. You probably would have found the mistake yourself.

Comment: remove $ sign in front of menu, so use like that $this->menu

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the dollar sign before menu, because you're referencing local variables

```
 $this->menu = $this->menu_model->generateTree($items=array());
```

Comment: ohh..I missed it. I found where the issue so many times. thanks @Jude

Answer (score 0):

`class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {`

```
private $menu;

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('menu_model');

    $this->menu = $this->menu_model->generateTree($items = array());
}

public function index() {
    $data['menu'] = $this->menu;
    $this->load->view('dashboard/dashboard', $data);
}
```

}

Comment: It Worked..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$` from `$this->$menu`

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('menu_model');

    $this->menu = $this->menu_model->generateTree($items=array());
}

public function index()
{        
    $data['menu'] = $this->menu;
    $this->load->view('dashboard/dashboard', $data);

}
```

Comment: It Worked..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `$menu` as below in your file, hope this solution help you.

```
$this->menu
```

Comment: It Worked..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

while accessing the class variable you need not to use **$** for second time after **$this**
so it would be like below code

for example

```
$this->variable_name
```

your code would be as follows

```
<?php

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

private $menu;

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('menu_model');

    $this->menu = $this->menu_model->generateTree($items = array());
}

public function index() {
    $data['menu'] = $this->menu;
    $this->load->view('dashboard/dashboard', $data);
}
```

}

Comment: It Worked..Thanks